# Laravel mix throws error on dynamic component loading

Tags: vue.js, laravel-mix

I am using laravel mix and vue. I am loading all components dynamically by defining routes in routes.js file.

```
{ path: '/network',   component:() =>  import('./components/network/NetworkComponent') },
```

when i run "npm run dev" or "npm run prod". all my routes are working fine and components are loaded correctly associated with each route. When i use npm run watch to add/change something and rebuild using npm run watch i am getting below error

```
app.js?t=1570291343:64 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?t=1570291343:64)
    at __webpack_require__.t (app.js?t=1570291343:162)
```

Comment: The issue is most likely that you don't have the babel plugin for syntax dynamic imports enabled.

Comment: i have this 
mix.babelConfig({
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'],
});
 in webpack.mix.js